# Dropdownlist and ViewData in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, viewdata, dropdownlistfor

I have a problem with my code. Iwan to make a dropdownlist in my View.cshtml using ViewData and @Html.Dropdownlist. But i get error while i compile it.
Here is my code :

This is the model

```
public class DeviceComponentModel
{
    public int devcomId { get; set; }
    public int devcomcomponentId { get; set; }
    public int? devcomdeviceId { get; set; }
    public ComponentModel Component { get; set; }
    public DeviceModel Device { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code in the controller.

```
public ActionResult addDevicecomponent()
{
    ViewData["Device"] = new SelectList(debuDB.Devices, "Id", "Name");
    ViewData["Component"] = new SelectList(debuDB.Components, "Id", "Name");
    DeviceComponentModel mdlDevicecom = new DeviceComponentModel();
    return View(mdlDevicecom);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult addDeviceComponent(DeviceComponentModel mdlDevicecom)
{
    try
    {
        DeviceComponent deviceComponent = new DeviceComponent()
        {
            Id = mdlDevicecom.devcomId,
            device_id = mdlDevicecom.devcomdeviceId,
            component_id = mdlDevicecom.devcomcomponentId
        };
        debuDB.DeviceComponents.InsertOnSubmit(deviceComponent);
        debuDB.SubmitChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View(mdlDevicecom);
    }
}
```

This is my code in the View

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.devcomdeviceId)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("device_0",ViewData["Device"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Choose Device")
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.devcomcomponentId)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("component_0",ViewData["Component"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Choose Component")
</div>
```

But when i compiled it i got the error like this:

> "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'device_0'."

I dont know why cant i get the error like that. I hope some of you can give the solution of this error.

Regards,

Comment: The error occurs when you return the view (in the `catch` block) because you have not reassigned the `SelectList`'s to the `ViewData` properties

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I've implement your suggest, but while i try to submitted, it don't save the data into database because it doesn't go to try block but to the catch block. Is there any wrong code in my try block statement?

Comment: You will have to debug your code and see where the error is occurring - could be multiple reasons

Comment: I have find the bug. It is in the InsertOnSubmit. It can do this action so that also go to catch block. Actually what's wrong? Please tell me

Comment: There is no way I can tell based on the code you have shown. You need to debug you code and when the exception is thrown, check the stack trace to find out what the error is.